# Show keyboard programmatically on specific display in Android app for multiscreen device

Tags: android, keyboard, android-multi-display

I have `Android` app in multiscreen device. In this code:

```
DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
Display[] displays = displayManager.getDisplays();
```

`displays` array size is 2.

And my question is: how to show programmatically keyboard for specific display, for example, `displays[1]`?